# Authenticate an iOS web app (licensing)

Tags: ios, iphone, security, authentication, iphone-standalone-web-app

We are having an iOS web app for the iPhone 6s. This app needs user authentication in the context of **licensing**. The user should be able to authenticate himself and must not be able to give his own license to someone else.

---

Here are the ideas I was thinking of *yet*:

#### 1: IMEI

If I could retrieve the IMEI using PHP or JavaScript, it would be a great start. But this is not possible, unless it's a native app. And that's just not an option here.

#### 2: Authentication token

Passing a secret authentication token through the URL, like a serial key could work. But the user could easily give it to someone else. And checking IP addresses to detect unlicensed use is not easy, because IP addresses of mobile devices change and make it hard to distinguish one user having different IP addresses from multiple users.

---

I'm trying hard to think outside the box. But is there any way to authenticate the user of this iPhone web app securely?

We don't want security through obscurity solutions here; It may be not possible to make it definitely impossible to bypass. But it should be as secure as possible.

Comment: Even a native app can't get the IMEI. Just get the user to authenticate using a username and password and track active sessions. If the user authenticates in a new session then terminate the old sessions

Comment: The user must be able to authenticate quick, i.e. without entering passwords and - for reasons I can't expose, the user could still give his license away with this method.

Comment: how do you propose to assign the license to a user in the first place? There is virtually nothing you can do on the client side because you cannot trust the client.

Comment: I'm aware that there is no entirely secure way. Trusting a client by passing his license token with the URL is the best I can think of yet. I'm still hoping for some sort of "device ID" and I'm also hoping that it's as hard to spoof as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately what you are trying to do is the opposite of what Apple tries to do. Apple makes it as hard as possible to identify and track devices, so there is no unique identifier available in the web browsers apart from what you put there.

Comment: Also, device-centric access seems to be at odds to how web apps are typically used. I have multiple devices, I want to use services on which ever device is at hand; phone, iPad etc. also mobile devices get replaced

Comment: Well, then it seems an authentication token is the only way. And unless the token is not an Url linking to a picture of the customer naked, I guess there is no way to really avoid sharing. I think we need to re-think the native/web app thing. Thank you so far.

Comment: I would avoid passing auth tokens, session ids, and similar via URL parameters as they tend to be logged by web servers as a default setting. Would a client side certificate passed in a post body be a worthwhile line of investigation?